# Should I remove outliers before combining the dataset or after combining the dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, data-cleaning

I am doing some exploratory data analysis on a custom dataset. I have 3 different data-frames:

1. df1 belonging to class 0.
2. df2 belonging to class 1.
3. df3 belonging to
   class 2.

I am doing k-means clustering on the combined data-frame (by combining df1, df2, df3). Should I remove outliers before combining the data-frames or after combining the data-frames?

I am removing outliers using IQR technique. I have been doing it before combining the data-frame but I was wondering if it is the right approach.

Comment: Why remove so-called outliers at all?

Comment: My next step is to see if k-means clustering does the job of clustering those 3 different classes. That is why I wanted to remove the outliers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should not create a negative effect since you mentioned you are doing exploratory data analysis. Keeping or removing outliers affect model performance when we perform machine learning, deep learning, or similar advanced modeling technique.

Comment: My next step is to see if k-means clustering does the job of clustering those 3 different classes. That is why I wanted to remove the outliers.

Comment: @HarshvardhanUppaluru ok. For exploratory data analysis no need to remove. For k-means, you need to remove (as needed) and possibly normalize the set. Upvote or mark my answer as correct if I answered your original question (whether or not you should remove outliers before exploratory data analysis).

Comment: What do you mean `it should not create a negative effect`? The presence of "outliers" can greatly affect the results of say clustering creating very different clusters.

Comment: @user2974951 you are misquoting my comment because you left out `..since you mentioned you are doing "exploratory data analysis".` as OP indicated in the original question.

Comment: My comment still holds, it makes no difference if you are doing exploratory or confirmatory analysis, your results will be affected by "outliers".

Comment: @user2974951 no. It does not hold. We use exploratory data analysis to (as the name implies) "explore" the data and create strategies to do either analytics, dashboarding, statistical analysis, statistical learning, classical machine learning, machine learning, deep learning, or other advanced techniques.